# Using openssl encryption for Apple's HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: http, http-live-streaming

Has anyone had any luck getting encrypted streaming to work with Apple's HTTP Live Streaming using openssl? It seems I'm almost there but my video doesn't play but I don't get any errors in Safari either (like "Video is unplayable" or "You don't have permission to play this video" when I got the key wrong).

```
#bash script:
keyFile="key.txt"
openssl rand 16 > $keyFile
hexKey=$(cat key.txt | hexdump -e '"%x"')
hexIV='0'
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in $fileName -out $encryptedFileName -p -nosalt -iv ${hexIV}  -K ${hexKey}


#my playlist file:
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:000020
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="key.txt"
#EXTINF:20, no desc
test.ts.enc
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I was using these docs as a guide:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming

Comment: You've encrypted the file. Why would you expect Safari to be able to "play" ciphertext?

Comment: For more context on this question:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/introduction/introduction.html

http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming

Comment: Hmmm... looks like you did everything right. The spec does not specify the padding, but that shouldn't hurt you until the very end if at all.

Comment: In newer version of openssl (>= 1.1.1) `-iv` is required if `-K` is given

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out... My hexdump command was wrong. It should be:

```
hexKey=$(cat key.txt | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"')
```

Answer (score 7):

Also keep in mind the following, if you have more than 1 TS "chunk", and you're looking for a bit-exact replacement for the Apple encryption pipeline.  By default, the Apple encryption tool updates the IV (initialization vector) parameter for each of the chunks, which "increases the strength of the cipher," according to the Pantos spec.

Implementing this just means that the sequence number needs to be encoded in hex and passed as the -iv parameter to openssl:

```
#!/bin/bash
keyFile="key.txt"
openssl rand 16 > $keyFile
hexKey=$(cat key.txt | hexdump -e '"%x"')
# hexIV='0'
for i in {0..number_of_TS_chunks}
do
    hexIV=`printf '%032x' $i`
    openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in $fileName -out $encryptedFileName -p -nosalt -iv ${hexIV} -K ${hexKey}
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Combining information from three of the above (the OP, the fix for hexdump and the IV information) yielded a working solution for [us](http://www.opensolutions.ie/blog/2010/08/http-streaming-with-encryption-under-linux/). Namely:

```
openssl rand 16 > static.key

key_as_hex=$(cat static.key | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"')

for i in {0..9}; do
    init_vector=`printf '%032x' $i`
    openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in video_low_$(($i+1)).ts -out video_low_enc_$(($i+1)).ts -p -nosalt -iv $init_vector -K $key_as_hex
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have the tools to experiment with this. It looks like you carefully followed the spec. One thing I would do is sniff the network do make sure the `key.txt` file is getting downloaded to Safari. I would also try explicitly picking the IV using the IV attribute of the EXT-X-KEY tag, e.g.

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="key.txt",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Yea, I tried setting the IV explicitly but I got the same result.

I can confirm that the key.txt is being fetched, and I've also got real errors from the video element by changing some bytes in key.txt ("You are not authorized to open this file").