# Open source AES-128 encryption for HLS?

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, aes, http-live-streaming

Apple has some really nice tools to segmenting solid media files to HLS and adding AES-128 encryption. However, they only run on Mac's and thus aren't very useful in a typical cloud environment where the machines run on Linux.

I'm looking for any existing tools and libraries that will help in adding AES-128 encryption to pre-segmented HLS. I don't believe this would be super complicated to implement. I'd like to write it in Ruby. Does anyone know of any tools or resources that will help?

Comment: AES encrypting anything is not that hard indeed. Coming up with a secure protocol *is*. Without prior experience, you are very likely to fail to invent one yourself that is secure. You should come up with one before you start programming. Unfortunately, that part is off topic here on stackoverflow...

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're saying? I'm just taking existing transport stream files and encrypting with AES-128. They will be served over HTTP/HTTPS

Comment: @owlstead the OP is talking about [HTTP Live Streaming Content Protection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html), it's DRM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using openssl encryption for Apple's HTTP Live Streaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010638/using-openssl-encryption-for-apples-http-live-streaming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [OpenSSL::Cipher](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) class in Ruby. Since the OpenSSL extension is basically a wrapper for native OpenSSL, this is really fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can fork and exec openssl to do the actual encryption. You most likely don't want to do the AES encryption in ruby because it will be ridiculously slow.

You can model your program after this shell script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3600805/759140

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working in Ruby and it seems very quick. It doesn't need to be that fast for my current needs, but it's good to  know that others got it working with CLI openssl.

Comment: It would only be slow in Ruby if the entire AES algorithm would be implemented in Ruby. But the OpenSSL extension wraps native code for the most part and is therefore almost as fast as "the real thing".

Comment: @emboss Yeah, that's probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG can transcode and encrypt HLS files

```
ffmpeg -y -i <file in> -hsl_time 10 -hls_key_info_file <key info file> -hls_segment_filename "encrupted-%d.ts" encrypted.m3u
```

You can find more info here:
[FFMPEG Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734578/ffmpeg-encryption)

AVCONV should also be able to, but I did not yet get it to work.