# FFMPEG Encryption

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, openssl, aes, http-live-streaming

I am doing a project with encrypting
video and I have a few questions for the procedure.

I used a command to transcode `mp4` to `HLS` with a `ts` segment duration of ~10 seconds.

First, I need to encrypt those videos with a key from database. However,
I have no idea for the encryption whether working with ffmpeg or not.

Second, if the encryption can work without ffmpeg, so what should I do? I have searched in google which includes something like openssl / aes but
there is no a detailed step for me to follow, even the ffmpeg link:
http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#srtp

Could anyone give me a hand, teaching me how to encrypt a video? Thanks to you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `ffmpeg`. You need to write the key from the database to a file, let's say `video.key`.

You need a second file, let's name it `key_info` which is the key info file. It has the following format:

```
key URI
key file path
IV (optional)
```

Eg:

```
http://example.com/video.key
video.key
```

You tell `ffmpeg` to use it to encrypt your segments with the `hls_key_info` argument:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -hls_time 10 -hls_key_info_file key_info playlist.m3u8
```

This will encrypt your segments with AES-128 in CBC mode and add the relevant tags to your playlist:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://example.com/video.key"
```

You can also manually encrypt the segments if you want with `openssl`. Here's an example script, where each IV is equal to the segment index:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ts_dir=/path/to/ts/

key_file=video.key
openssl rand 16 > $key_file
enc_key=$(hexdump -v -e '16/1 "%02x"' $key_file)

pushd $ts_dir

ts_cnt=$(ls *.ts | wc -l)
((ts_cnt--))

i=0
for i in $(seq -f "%01g" 0 $ts_cnt); do
    iv=$(printf '%032x' $i)
    ts_file=segment-$i.ts

    echo [$i] $ts_file

    openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in $ts_file -out encrypted_${ts_file} -nosalt -iv $iv -K $enc_key
done

popd
```

Comment: After running the command, the following error appears:

Unrecognized option 'hls_key_info_file'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Comment: @rickyma924 you may be using an outdated version of `ffmpeg`. Build it from source or grab a [package/static build](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Here's a link to the `hls` documentation: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-2

Comment: @rickyma924 post the full command please, I will try it. If you installed a new `ffmpeg` make sure you're using the right one `which ffmpeg`.

Comment: ffmpeg -i bunny.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -hls_time 10 -hls_key_info_file file.keyinfo playlist.m3u8

Comment: Works for me. Do a `ffmpeg -version` and post the result.

Comment: ffmpeg version git-2015-02-13-849ad51 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)


Maybe the one I downloaded is a static version and cannot replace my original one

Comment: @rickyma924 check the binary path with `which` to make sure you're using the correct one.

Comment: when I use -which, it shows me ffmpeg stored in ~/bin

Comment: Did you use the `git` version or the `release`. Try the `git`.

Comment: how to make the static ffmpeg to be the default one? is it just do export static/ffmpeg/path:$PATH?

Comment: I don't know where you installed it but run it from its directory, eg: `./ffmpeg -i ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90417/discussion-between-aergistal-and-rickyma924).

Comment: Is it possible to use this technique to decrypt a live stream?

Comment: @chovy This is encryption not decryption. But yes you can both encrypt or decrypt a live AES-128 HLS stream.

Comment: what options do i pass to ffmpeg to decrypt it?

Comment: @chovy None, you just point it to the `m3u8` and it will use the `EXT-X-KEY` information in it automatically.

Comment: I was hoping to override the key in the playlist.m3u8 -- as I don't have control over that.

Comment: Newby question. Where do I get a key?

Comment: @StormyKnight you generate one: `openssl rand 16 > $key_file`. It can be anything as long as it's 16 bytes long.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve some sort DRM solution using this encryption method? Using ffmpeg, I'd like to be able to encrypt a stream with a user's public key so that it can only be decrypted with that user's private key but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: @aergistal Thank you, very helpful example. Do I understand hls manifest KEY-URL is just a php/servlet/static file url to the raw encryption key file response. It does not do any dash-widevine/playready level PKI key exchange server things? So it's easy to have a own customized hls key delivery url entrypoint?

Comment: @Whome Yes it's just the raw key, not DRM.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the newest (see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/10441#comment:1) version of `ffmpeg`, you can create an encrypted HLS stream from your video file with one single simple command:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f hls -hls_enc 1 stream.m3u8
```

This will generate a strong (cryptographically secure pseudorandom) key, save it (in binary format) to the `stream.m3u8.key` file (the key file name depends on the playlist file name), encrypt all chunks (segments) using it, and add the corresponding string to the `stream.m3u8` playlist file so that players can decrypt the chunks (segments) and play the video:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="stream.m3u8.key"
```

If you already have your own key, you can use it (in hexadecimal string format) by adding `-hls_enc_key` option:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f hls -hls_enc 1 -hls_enc_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb stream.m3u8
```

If you need to generate a strong (cryptographically secure pseudorandom) key in hexadecimal string format, you can use `openssl`:

```bash
openssl rand -hex 16
```