# How do I decrypt the HLS stream to a .ts file when I have the key and IV?

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have access to all the .ts files.
My **.m3u8** starts like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:13
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localserver/get_key?title_id=144", IV=0x4d1acfe1962002a4abedb8b68c65fa93
#EXTINF:12.066667,
1500_144_00000.ts
#EXTINF:9.000000,
1500_144_00001.ts
EXTINF:9.000000,
1500_144_00002.ts
...
```

... and the .m3u8 continues to show all the .ts files. It gives me the **IV**, and my **Access key** is `f0d3321327cbaa1aa9ddba07801607442bebaad65b17ca75a15affd5`

No I've been searching my brain and the web for an answer on how to decrypt the .ts files (or the concatenated file) and I have seen suggestions using both **openssl** and **ffmpeg** but I can not seem to reach all the way with either tool.

From what I've figured I can use the IV and Access_key to decrypt the stream using openssl. I have used the IV=4d1acfe1962002a4abedb8b68c65fa93 (removed 0x).

I have so far tried to with the concatenated file:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in concatenatedfile.ts -out decrypted_concatenatedfile.ts -nosalt -iv 4d1acfe1962002a4abedb8b68c65fa93 -K f0d3321327cbaa1aa9ddba07801607442bebaad65b17ca75a15affd5
```

But this just gives me

```
bad decrypt
139793444538016:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:539:
```

I've seen suggestions that use a .key file and convert that to a readable format. But since I don't have a .key file, but a ready string, I figure this is where I fail.

I've tried using ffmpeg in accordance to [this beautiful post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34244568/9143107) by [@aergistal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4663670/aergistal).

```
ffmpeg -i my.m3u8 -c copy output.ts
```

But here too I seem to fail with my long string key.

Any suggestions on how to proceed using openssl or ffmpeg are very welcome.

Kindly

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

AES-128 means the key is 128 bits, 16 bytes, or 32 hex characters. Your string is much longer, meaning it cant be the correct key.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious how to achive this as well, and ended up putting the key into it's own file, say `video.key` and modifying the `m3u8` file to point to the local file instead:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="video.key",IV=0xc9...
```

Then you have to make sure you pass `-allowed_extensions ALL` to ffmpeg during conversion.

```
ffmpeg -allowed_extensions ALL -i video.m3u8 -c copy out.mp4
```