# Saving an m3u8 stream in UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, uwp, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I started creating my first UWP app and I got stuck at some place. I've been trying to download a video file from a link and that that's a m3u8 stream. I'm not sure how to achieve downloading of this file.

Here's the link to the video (m3u8 ) file : https://pastebin.com/Zu4RQCMu

```
http://dl.v.vrv.co/evs/726f2912f654a28e481f451d11d33bc6/assets/36ecef5244e7a9ddc19bf0cb7377a1e2_3557698.mp4/master.m3u8?Policy=ewoiU3RhdGVtZW50IjpbCnsKIlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cCo6Ly9kbC52LnZydi5jby9ldnMvNzI2ZjI5MTJmNjU0YTI4ZTQ4MWY0NTFkMTFkMzNiYzYvYXNzZXRzLzM2ZWNlZjUyNDRlN2E5ZGRjMTliZjBjYjczNzdhMWUyXzM1NTc2OTgubXA0L21hc3Rlci5tM3U4IiwKIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6ewoiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE1NDkzNzU4MzV9Cn0KfQpdCn0_&amp;Signature=NuopmOByY18fNPuTD7WU4JiVFfryRJO2LQenfnP7rxwYWQ89T08u9tw1X4pa6d0R-wA0mPQeI-NqK7xHXNh6-5UvNiW5W1u9vhjl0U~rSm3U4EPwzkmbHnYlEWbIzcJSQNWlZgFOSfQZ63ojMrzjddSWr1ZvcTLBqtl3EK-hmcPSoRFX8ukEnuTHrQAtN~d9sF5q7S043hLh0P351BVwMr1AgpsFeXuFxGbl1Mxe7TIoC7MCQj-MhUF3~XOhBPoDKXHT6RAULCfVba50qutu4IU-9BrXNGwFXYGPnHLyv1HUcuQkLJxU8bwcqFHUbYyJZmS43AtpBCt7ME6F0WsaiA__&amp;Key-Pair-Id=DLVR
```

Can someone guide me here. Thanks.

I tried downloading the segment files from the m3u8 file I got. I got the encrypted `.ts` files, those are segments I know. So, should I be decrypting them and then stitch them together? If yes, how? Is there anything built in C# itself that can do this job or do I have to do something else?

Comment: maybe some help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235397/decrypting-and-combining-ts-audio-files-with-m3u8

Comment: External tool like `ffmpeg` is being used There's no control over that. I want to stay in the application and handle it internally. Otherwise, I can start a process and run the command there. But, that's a weird functionality. And packaging `ffmpeg` with my UWP app, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Have you checked the [Adaptive streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming) document and [Adaptive streaming sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/AdaptiveStreaming)? It might be that you want.

Comment: Yep, tried these. But, they wouldn't work. I haven't debugged properly, but the player wouldn't even show up. That's the very first thing I tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg to download m3u8 streams

or you can use youtube-dl :- https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl

For Ffmpeg you can use this command to download most of m3u8 streams :-

> ffmpeg -i "here put your m3u8 link" -c copy outuput.mp4

This command will concat all .ts files into one single output.mp4 file

Comment: @Xonshiz already said he was opposed to using an external program though "External tool like ffmpeg is being used There's no control over that. I want to stay in the application and handle it internally. Otherwise, I can start a process and run the command there. But, that's a weird functionality. And packaging ffmpeg with my UWP app, I'm not sure how to do that."

Comment: The point is you should not!
FFMpeging is too heavy of a task for it to be run on the client, even a native UWP app or even C/C++ libraries that run directly on the client. 

Instead, the better approach is to run the job on the server and provide the result to the client via REST APIs or similar methods.