# Native iOS video player fails on HLS encrypted with openssl

Tags: ios, video, encryption, openssl, http-live-streaming

I'm having an issue with encrypting HLS using openssl. As described here: [Using openssl encryption for Apple's HTTP Live Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010638/using-openssl-encryption-for-apples-http-live-streaming) I'm using following script to encrypt TS files created by ffmpeg:

```
encyptionKeyFile="crypt.key"
openssl rand 16 > $encyptionKeyFile
encryptionKey=`cat $encyptionKeyFile | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"'`

splitFilePrefix="$fileName.split."
encryptedSplitFilePrefix="${splitFilePrefix}enc."

numberOfTsFiles=`ls ${splitFilePrefix}*.ts | wc -l`

for i in {0..$numberOfTsFiles}; do
    initializationVector=`printf '%032x' $i`
    openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in ${splitFilePrefix}$i.ts -out ${encryptedSplitFilePrefix}$i.ts -nosalt -iv $initializationVector -K $encryptionKey
    rm ${splitFilePrefix}$i.ts
done
```

ffmpeg command used to generate TS file is following:

```
ffmpeg -i $file -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -segment_list $mainPlaylistName -segment_time 10 ${splitFilePrefix}%d.ts
```

M3U8 playlist file looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI=crypt.key
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:19
#EXTINF:11.875000,
BigBuckBunnyMovie.split.enc.0.ts
#EXTINF:11.166667,
BigBuckBunnyMovie.split.enc.1.ts
#EXTINF:12.500000,
BigBuckBunnyMovie.split.enc.2.ts
#EXTINF:12.166667,
BigBuckBunnyMovie.split.enc.3.ts
#EXTINF:8.375000,
...
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I thought that it might be a problem with encoding or something with ffmpeg command format but the thing is that encrypted stream doesn't work on native iOS player (MPMoviePlayerController) but works fine on VLC. What is more, unencrypted stream (using TS files produced by ffmpeg) works on both native player and VLC!

Can you suggest me what can I do to be able to play it on native iOS video player?

Thanks for all your responses!

Comment: Can you show (at least a snippet) of the variant m3u8 file?

Comment: Ok, I added it to question.

Comment: Is the iOS player requesting the crypt.key URI? I'm not sure that it will accept a relative URL like that.

Comment: I think it shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, if I change it to "URI=http://localhost/crypt.key" if fails as well.

Comment: Maybe try with a protocol (http://)

Comment: The same - nothing happens, player does not request the key.

Comment: it's a long shot, but maybe put the EXT-X-KEY line after the EXT-X-TARGETDURATION? You're certain the player isn't even requesting the key (meaning you can see that from the server side)?

Comment: And in the referenced Q&A, they're using hexdump to format the key file -- is there a reason you're not?

Comment: 1. Changing EXT-X-KEY line with EXT-X-TARGETDURATION didn't help
2. I can access server side so I'm sure that player doesn't request the key
3. I'm using hex dump but I didn't put the whole script in the question. I updated the question so it contains hexdump now.

Comment: The draft spec states that the URI value is a quoted string (section 3.4.4). Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I updated my previous answer to be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The draft spec states that the URI value is a quoted string. See section [3.4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-12#section-3.4.4) of the draft spec.

Comment: I wonder if you'd be so kind as to take a look at my new HLS video question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60852109/470749