# Why won't this encrypted HLS video play on iOS (but works on Windows Chrome via hls.js library)?

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am trying to play an MP4 test video.

My `/home/vagrant/Code/example/public/hls_hls.keyInfo` is:

```
https://example.com/hls.key
/home/vagrant/Code/example/public/hls_hls.key
467216aae8a26fb699080812628031955e304a66e9e4480f9b70d31d8fe94e9a
```

My `/home/vagrant/Code/example/public/hls_hls.key` was generated using PHP: `hex2bin('467216aae8a26fb699080812628031955e304a66e9e4480f9b70d31d8fe94e9a')`

The [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2) command for encrypting the video as HLS playlist with "ts" files:

```
'/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' 'storage/app/sample_media2/2020-02-27/Sample_Videos_5.mp4' 
'-c:v' 'libx264' '-s:v' '1920x1080' '-crf' '20' '-sc_threshold' '0' '-g' '48' 
'-keyint_min' '48' '-hls_list_size' '0' 
'-hls_time' '10' '-hls_allow_cache' '0' '-b:v' '4889k' '-maxrate' '5866k' 
'-hls_segment_type' 'mpegts' '-hls_fmp4_init_filename' 'output_init.mp4' 
'-hls_segment_filename' 'storage/app/public/test/output_1080p_%04d.ts' 
'-hls_key_info_file' '/home/vagrant/Code/example/public/hls_hls.keyInfo' 
'-strict' '-2' '-threads' '12' 'storage/app/public/test/output_1080p.m3u8'
```

Then, I know from https://caniuse.com/#search=hls that Windows Chrome won't be able to play the HLS video without a library, so I use https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/, and **Windows Chrome successfully plays the encrypted video!**

**However, iOS Safari is unable to play it (with or without the hls.js library).**

On iOS Safari, when I try to play the video, I see just a quick glimpse (less than a second) where **the screen shows 0:15, so it must be reading and decrypting enough to know the correct duration of the video.**

So, to debug, I log events:

```
const nativeHlsEvents = ['play', 'playing', 'abort', 'error', 'canplaythrough', 'waiting', 'loadeddata', 'loadstart', 'progress', 'timeupdate', 'volumechange'];
$.each(nativeHlsEvents, function (i, eventType) {
    video.addEventListener(eventType, (event) => {//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement
        console.log(eventType, event);
        if (eventType === 'error') {
            console.error(video.error);//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/error
        }
    });
});
```

I see in the console log:

```
loadstart, {"isTrusted":true}
progress, {"isTrusted":true}
play, {"isTrusted":true}
waiting, {"isTrusted":true}
error, {"isTrusted":true}
video.error, {}
```

I don't know how to find more details about the error.

Note that even though Windows Chrome successfully plays the video, it too shows warnings in the console log:

```
{"type":"mediaError","details":"fragParsingError","fatal":false,"reason":"TS packet did not start with 0x47","frag":{"...
{"type":"mediaError","details":"fragParsingError","fatal":false,"reason":"no audio/video samples found","frag":{...
```

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would need to buy a newer iPhone.**

I see at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_6#Software and https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/supported-iphone-models-iphe3fa5df43/ios that “6s” is the oldest hardware that iOS 13 supports, and https://caniuse.com/#search=hls says HLS needs >=13.2.

Comment: I've now asked what encryption approach I should have used instead: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/73726/14834

Answer (score 0):

Iphone devices not supported media source extension.

You should by user agent checking has iphone?

If be right, you should use iphone native video player for play hls video type or more video type